# Alternative to :before or :after for adding content through CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a class of elements

```
input.na:before { content: "n/a"; }
```

and I just noticed that this is not working on older versions of Internet Explorer. If possible, I want to make this work in Internet Explorer without editing the HTML of the page to include a new element containing "n/a". So is there a way I can apply changes only in the CSS that will give me the equivalent behavior across all browsers?

Comment: Unfortunately, you're out of luck. Pseudo elements are the only way to append content without JS or altering the markup.

Comment: use a background image, only on IE<=7, in which you write "n/a". It's an awful idea anyway

Comment: input and img are of those elements that cannot produce these virtual boxes, you need a wrapper around it, a label eventually won't hurt